# ggplot2 legend when each layer has a single variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry for this basic question but I'm new to ggplot2 and am probably not using correct terminology in my search for an answer. I have a scatterplot with two layers. The base is individual observations at various times and the overlay is the mean of those observations at the same times. All data is in long format. Sample code below produces the correct plot but I can't figure out how to create the legend that links + to individual observations and circles to the means of those observations. Thanks for helping a newbie.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)  
x <- rep(x, each = 3)  
y <- c(3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 3, 8, 9, 6)  
df1 <- data.frame(x, y)
df2 <- aggregate(y ~ x, df1, mean)
p1 <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(pch = 3, size =2) + # Individual observations
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + # Means
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x, y =y)) # Connect means
```

Comment: Thanks. Nothing like missing the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

That is because to display a legend you have to specify a `shape` argument in the `aes()` function that maps data to visual parameters.

The easiest way would be to combine your two dataframes and add a third column specifying the type...

```
df3 <- as.data.frame(rbind(df1, df2))
df3$type <- rep(c("Ind. Obs.", "Means"), c(nrow(df1), nrow(df2)))
```

Then you need to specify the `shape` parameter to correspond to `df3$type`. Also to get the shapes that you want you will need to call `scale_shape_manual()`.

```
p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df3, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = type)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(3, 19)) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x, y =y)) # Connect means
p1
```